# Loading dynamic grid view

Tags: android

I have few images which are retrieved from my web service.
I want to display these images in grid view in android.
How can i do this??

Thanks,
Sneha

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See the following url to create a gridview

[How to create grid view](http://developer.android.com/guide/tutorials/views/hello-gridview.html)

you have to set image inside `getView()` method

If you have image in the form of bitmap then use

```
imageview.setImageBitmap(bm);
```

If you have image in the form of drawable then use

```
imageview.setImageDrawable(drawable);
```

If you have image in your resource example if image is present in drawable folder then use

```
imageview.setImageResource(R.drawable.image);
```

If you have path of image then use

```
imageview.setImageURI(Uri.parse("pathofimage));
```

If you have image in byte array format then you can convert that byte array into Bitmap and use any of the above method.

Thanks
Deepak

Answer (score 0):

There are different image loader libraries which will help to load these images in ImageView

Inside getView() use:

Picasso library:

`Picasso.with(mContext).load("http://url.com/image.jpeg")into(imageView);`

or Glide library:

`Glide.with(mContext).load("").into(imageView)`

Read this article about three image loader library.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/29558169/5056336