# How to download image faster in android Volley/Picasso/Glide any other?

Tags: android, image, android-volley, picasso, android-glide

I am developing project in which i have to download some images from server. I have tried these 3 methods.

Picasso:

```
Picasso.with(context).load(image).into(holder.image);
```

Glide:

```
Glide.with(context).load(image).into(holder.image);
```

Volley:

```
imageLoader.get(image, new ImageLoader.ImageListener() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(ImageLoader.ImageContainer response, boolean isImmediate) {
            holder.image.setImageBitmap(response.getBitmap());
        }

        @Override
        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {

        }
    });
```

No doubt, all these methods are working very well in fast Internet connection.
but in 2G It takes too much time to download image of 20kb - 25kb.
I also have tried image resizing and everything. But doesn't get good result from that.
I saw application like Amazon or Flipkart or any e-commerce application these apps are working very well in slow internet connection and dowanloads all images in good resolution also. So, I want some expert solutions on these problem.

Comment: you can try with [fresco](http://frescolib.org/)

Comment: If you use this library it first time it takes time to download image and after that it automatically loads image faster as it display images from cache

Comment: check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29363321/picasso-v-s-imageloader-v-s-fresco-vs-glide You can try fresco

Comment: If you compare these three libraries i think Glide is best. Glide supports fetching, decoding, and displaying video stills, images, and animated GIFs. And at least its faster then Picasso.

Answer (score 2):

Glide , Picasso are just Fetch image from the server and show it. if your network speed is less the the images take longer to to load. you need to re-size the images in the server side. Using [WebP](https://developers.google.com/speed/webp/?hl=en) format instead of JPEG or PNG will help to reduce size without reducing quality.

Note: you can use [Thumbor](https://github.com/thumbor/thumbor) to accomplish this easily.

Comment: Thank you. I will try this. I also have e-commerce project. Right now, In this project have only 20 images so it will be easy for me to change format of all these. But, What to do in e-commerce it has around 1 lac products. I cant change all those image's format. So what to do in that.

Answer (score 0):

If you have to download individual image on some click and save them to sdcard . Them Android's DownLoadManager class is the perfect and easy solution for this . Or If you want to show a heap of image in your application from web then Universal Image Loader is useful as same as Volley and Picasso . For downloading image Faster you have to reduce their size .Use WebP format instead of Jpeg or PNG at server end .

Answer (score 0):

If caching is not required and downloading direct from network then Picasso is a good option. If caching is required then use AQuery for images(or large images). There are multiple options of caching in AQuery.