# Load 10 image on first page

Tags: android, loadimage

I use this method to load 10 image on first page  but i have one problem.
first image takes a lot of time to load. After first image other image loading fast.
I don`t know why?

calling method `new DownloadImageTask((ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView_bb1).execute(db.getURLimgMahsol(id_bb2));`

loadImage method

```
private class DownloadImageTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Bitmap> {
        ImageView bmImage;

        public DownloadImageTask(ImageView bmImage) {
            this.bmImage = bmImage;

        }

        protected Bitmap doInBackground(String... urls) {
            String urldisplay = urls[0];
            Bitmap mIcon11 = null;
            try {
                InputStream in = new java.net.URL(urldisplay).openStream();
                mIcon11 = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(in);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                Log.e("Error", e.getMessage());
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            return mIcon11;
        }

        protected void onPostExecute(Bitmap result) {
            bmImage.setImageBitmap(result);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Yes.I edit problem

Answer (score 1):

Use Glide, Picasso or some other image loader. 
Also it's not good practice to hold reference on UI element in AsyncTask, or to have private inner AsyncTask class.
You can see [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=jtlRNNhane0) why.

Answer (score 1):

Check that you call `DownloadImageTask` with `execute()` and not with `get()`. Executing `get()` will **block** your UI until the task is finished.

**Please DON'T reinvent the wheel!** There is many good library to handle efficiently loading an image from url.

Hope this helps!!

Answer (score -1):

Probably you start 10 `AsyncTask`'s one by one, so UI gets freeze.
You should make queue: start first `AsyncTask` -> `onPostExecute` start second and so on.

---

I suggest you to use [Glide](https://github.com/bumptech/glide).
[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29363321/picasso-v-s-imageloader-v-s-fresco-vs-glide/) is the discussion about Glide and other ImageLoaders.

Comment: Tnx for your answer I read Glide
but
I don`t know how i can using this 
should i have import ?

Comment: @SobhanMoradi so you don't know how to use Gradle dependencies in Android Studio? Google will help you!

Comment: AsyncTasks always run on one thread, so no matter how many you run at one they will run one after other.