# Picasso vs Fresco

Tags: android, picasso, fresco

I am working on one Photo Editing Application. For that application i was using Universal Image Loader Library. But while using this library i got some issues like when i am trying to load more than four images i get `java.lang.OutOfMemoryError` exception. One of my friend suggest me to use another library.

I have found some alternative libraries like Picasso , Fresco , Glide etc.
But now i am confused with Picasso and fresco. Can anybody suggest me which is the best?

Comment: Also: [this](https://twitter.com/jessewilson/status/581235604740042752)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check [this link on stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29363321/picasso-v-s-imageloader-v-s-fresco-vs-glide). They discuss about it.
In my personal opinion, I like how picasso work, but i never really tested Fresco. So picasso has cool features, but check the link to find more about it..

Answer (score -2):

fresco is created by FaceBook team.It's function is very good!

Comment: You have to be more specefic and give some details about the question !