# Android library Picasso or Glide?

Tags: android, android-studio, picasso, android-glide

What is a better library for Android. Picasso or Glide and why? 
I'm using Picasso at this moment but the images are loading very slow. Is Glide faster then Picasso?

Comment: Your question is primarily opinion-based, which is not appropriate for this site. Nevertheless, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29363321/picasso-v-s-imageloader-v-s-fresco-vs-glide

Comment: Many good questions generate some degree of opinion based on expert experience, but answers to this question will tend to be almost entirely based on opinions, rather than facts, references, or specific expertise.

Comment: https://medium.com/@multidots/glide-vs-picasso-930eed42b81d

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Neither Glide nor Picasso is perfect. The way Glide loads an image to memory and do the caching is better than Picasso which let an image loaded far faster. In addition, it also helps preventing an app from popular OutOfMemoryError. GIF Animation loading is a killing feature provided by Glide. Anyway Picasso decodes an image with better quality than Glide.

https://inthecheesefactory.com/blog/get-to-know-glide-recommended-by-google/en