# Issues in Recycler view and Card View

Tags: java, android, android-recyclerview

I want to display card view but it doesnot display it shows fatal exception can any one solve this error with your programming skills.please see all layouts and classes?

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
 List<Person> persons;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    RecyclerView  rv = (RecyclerView)findViewById(R.id.recycle);
    rv.setHasFixedSize(true);
    initializeData();
    LinearLayoutManager ll = new LinearLayoutManager(this);
    rv.setLayoutManager(ll);
    RvAdapter rvAdapter = new RvAdapter(persons);
    rv.setAdapter(rvAdapter);

}

private void initializeData() {

    persons = new ArrayList<>();
    persons.add(new Person("Anilkumar","23 years",R.drawable.anil));
    persons.add(new Person("Prashanthi","21 years",R.drawable.inr));
}

}
```

Person class

```
public class Person
{
String name;
String age;
int photoId;

Person(String name,String age,int photoId)
{
    this.name = name;
    this.age = age;
    this.photoId = photoId;
}

}
```

RVadapter class

```
public class RvAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<RvAdapter.PersonViewHolder>
{


private List<Person> persons;
RvAdapter(List<Person> persons)
{
    this.persons = persons;
}

@Override
public PersonViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    View v = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.cardlayout,parent,false);
    PersonViewHolder pvh = new PersonViewHolder(v);
    return pvh;
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(PersonViewHolder holder, int position) {
        holder.personName.setText(persons.get(position).name);
    holder.personName.setText(persons.get(position).age);
    holder.personPhoto.setImageResource(persons.get(position).photoId);
}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {

    return persons.size();
}

@Override
public void onAttachedToRecyclerView(RecyclerView recyclerView) {
    super.onAttachedToRecyclerView(recyclerView);
}

public static class PersonViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder
{
    CardView cardView;
    TextView personName;
    TextView personAge;
    ImageView personPhoto;
    public PersonViewHolder(View itemView) {
        super(itemView);
        cardView = (CardView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.card);
        personName = (TextView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.text);
        personAge = (TextView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.text2);
        personPhoto = (ImageView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.image);
    }
}
}
```

Logcat error

```
06-20 22:51:57.126 5433-5433/com.example.anilkumar.recyclerview E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
java.lang.OutOfMemoryError
at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.nativeDecodeAsset(Native Method)
at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeStream(BitmapFactory.java:483)
at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeResourceStream(BitmapFactory.java:351)
at android.graphics.drawable.Drawable.createFromResourceStream(Drawable.java:773)
at android.content.res.Resources.loadDrawable(Resources.java:1940)
at android.content.res.Resources.getDrawable(Resources.java:664)
at android.support.v4.content.ContextCompat.getDrawable(ContextCompat.java:368)
at android.support.v7.internal.widget.TintManager.getDrawable(TintManager.java:177)
at android.support.v7.internal.widget.TintManager.getDrawable(TintManager.java:170)
at android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatImageHelper.setImageResource(AppCompatImageHelper.java:53)
at android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatImageView.setImageResource(AppCompatImageView.java:74)
at com.example.anilkumar.recyclerview.RvAdapter.onBindViewHolder(RvAdapter.java:49)
at com.example.anilkumar.recyclerview.RvAdapter.onBindViewHolder(RvAdapter.java:16)
at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$Adapter.onBindViewHolder(RecyclerView.java:5746)
at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$Adapter.bindViewHolder(RecyclerView.java:5779)
at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$Recycler.getViewForPosition(RecyclerView.java:5016)
at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$Recycler.getViewForPosition(RecyclerView.java:4892)
at android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager$LayoutState.next(LinearLayoutManager.java:2029)
at android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager.layoutChunk(LinearLayoutManager.java:1414)
at android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager.fill(LinearLayoutManager.java:1377)
at android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager.onLayoutChildren(LinearLayoutManager.java:578)
at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView.dispatchLayoutStep2(RecyclerView.java:3239)
at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView.onMeasure(RecyclerView.java:2767)
at android.view.View.measure(View.java:12723)
at android.widget.RelativeLayout.measureChildHorizontal(RelativeLayout.java:594)
at android.widget.RelativeLayout.onMeasure(RelativeLayout.java:376)
at android.view.View.measure(View.java:12723)
at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:4698)
at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:293)
at android.support.v7.internal.widget.ContentFrameLayout.onMeasure(ContentFrameLayout.java:135)
at android.view.View.measure(View.java:12723)
at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:4698)
```

[card layout](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7VI7s.png)
[recycle layout](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YqhuW.png)

Comment: what is your exception. Can you provide logcat ?

Comment: see the above there is logcat errorr

Comment: do you have big size images  ?

Comment: yes i have big images

Answer (score 0):

You have big images you mentioned it, you must take care of memory issues when you handling too big sized images.
You can use [Picasso](http://square.github.io/picasso/) or [Universal Image Loader](https://github.com/nostra13/Android-Universal-Image-Loader) or [Glide](https://github.com/bumptech/glide)

Theese libraries will load your images asynchronously , and you dont get any Memory issues.

One of my biggest image size till today is like `(4560x5250)` and i didnt get any memory issues , but if you want smooth scroll you can decrease image size in `Picasso`.

Currently im using `Picasso` in my `RecyclerView`.I can give example of `Picasso` like :

In your `onBindViewHolder` :

```
@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(PersonViewHolder holder, int position) {
holder.personName.setText(persons.get(position).name);
holder.personAge.setText(persons.get(position).age);
Picasso.with(context).load(persons.get(position).photoId).into(holder.personPhoto);

}
```

Also you can find comparison about theese libraries : [picasso-v-s-imageloader-v-s-fresco-vs-glide](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29363321/picasso-v-s-imageloader-v-s-fresco-vs-glide)

Comment: output comes but first textview did not display only second text view display is there any solution to over come

Comment: can you provide any screenshot

Comment: in my question click on enter my image description once then u find the image

Comment: what is problem here, can you give me what you want to do

Comment: Actually i m entering two text views in one card name and age but it display only age text....not show name text that is problem what i do now

Comment: if you post your row's xml i can help you !

Comment: please see below the question cardlayout and recycle layout

Comment: How to share with u any id u have

Comment: ıf you change this part of code you will beat problem : `@Override
        public void onBindViewHolder(PersonViewHolder holder, int position) {
            holder.personName.setText(persons.get(position).name);
            holder.personAge.setText(persons.get(position).age);
            holder.personPhoto.setImageResource(persons.get(position).photoId);
        }`

Comment: that is correct i think what i can change now in code

Comment: in your rvadapter class delete onBindViewHolder code. And put code in my comment

Comment: both are same in comment and my code ii cant understand properly sir

Comment: if you do what i am saying come with screenshot i will tell you

Comment: sir get it but how both are same but how its working

Comment: so funny i cantt saw i gave both person names

Comment: its not same my friend , i think you must open your eyes :) if you see `holder.personAge.setText(persons.get(position).age);`  this line different !

Comment: so funny sir.thank you for open my eyes.can u help me in another programme?

Comment: you can create questions and always im here

Comment: so the question is retrieve data from sqlite databse and display as a card view sir . i can send code by codeshare in 2 mins

Comment: @A.asha its not like that. You must search google and stackoverflow firstly. Make some effort and create a new question if you have issues still.Stackoverflow works like that. Noone can help you directly. You must make some effort. Please search and work a bit and come with result !

Comment: yes i can insert data into database but does not display cardview it shows exception

Comment: https://codeshare.io/UOyrB once check it.it shows fatal exception in rvadapter class