# <Image /> component is not working with external URL on Android

Tags: android, image, http, react-native

Does anyone know why `<Image />` component with external(*HTTPS*) *URL* is not  working correctly on Android?

I've tried to render avatar but Android just skip this `<Image />` component like it does not exist.

`<Image source={{
    url: "https://yabs.yandex.ru/resource/B4_LwOqnl6akXYQRO4jj2R_banana_20141031_1.png",
  }} style={{width: 148, height: 90}} />`

I'm a newbie in RN and Andriod, thanks in advance.

**Update:**

the problem was with `url` property. React Native uses `uri` instead.

Answer (score 0):

For **Android**

You will have to use something like [Universal Image Loader](https://github.com/nostra13/Android-Universal-Image-Loader).
Because providing http url to `<image />` will not work.

Other libraries available : Picasso and Glide image loader

**OR**

Alternatively you will have to manually get image from url and assign it

```
URL url = new URL("http://XXXXX");
Bitmap bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(url.openConnection().getInputStream());
imageView.setImageBitmap(bmp);
```

And

For **React** js : [react-native-image-cache](https://github.com/Anthonyzou/react-native-image-cache)

Comment: Thanks!
For react native I found _Universal Image Loader_'s wrapper - [react-native-image-cache](https://github.com/Anthonyzou/react-native-image-cache)

Comment: Updated my answer. Thanks

Comment: But, seems React Native uses https://github.com/facebook/fresco (see: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29363321/picasso-v-s-imageloader-v-s-fresco-vs-glide) under the hood for image caching. The question is, why it's not works?

Answer (score 0):

You have invalid syntax. Correct `source` property is `uri` not `url`.

Comment: yeah, I know. But it's to strange that it works on the iOS.