# Out of memory exception while loading image to imageview

Tags: android, out-of-memory, android-imageview

The app is getting crashed because of out of memory exception while loading images from internal storage for that am using below code

```
ImageHandler.getSharedInstance(context).load(imgFile)
            .skipMemoryCache().memoryPolicy(MemoryPolicy.NO_STORE,MemoryPolicy.NO_CACHE)
            .fit().into(imageView);

public class ImageHandler {

private static Picasso instance;

public static Picasso getSharedInstance(Context context)
{
    if(instance == null)
    {
        instance = new Picasso.Builder(context).executor(Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor()).memoryCache(Cache.NONE).indicatorsEnabled(false).build();
    }
    return instance;
}
```

}

but now app is not crashing but it is unable to load the image (Showing empty blank screen)

Comment: How big is the resolution of the image?

Comment: 2048*1536 am using this image for setting background of a tablet

Comment: That's quite a large image. It may eat a lot of RAM.

Comment: so whats is the better way to load without losing its image quality

Comment: Take a look at [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29363321/picasso-v-s-imageloader-v-s-fresco-vs-glide). You can use any library you like, here some are mentioned.

Comment: is this libraries solves out of memory exception?

Comment: They should, yes. Please read about them a bit and see which one fits your needs best.

Comment: No problem mate. Have fun coding!