# Can you explain internal implementation of image loading while considering performance issue? which is the best?

Tags: android

I am new to this image loading concept. Can you please explain internal implementation of image loading while considering performance issue?

Comment: The answer lies here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29363321/picasso-v-s-imageloader-v-s-fresco-vs-glide

Comment: Check this for a detailed study and results https://inthecheesefactory.com/blog/get-to-know-glide-recommended-by-google/en

Answer (score 0):

Their differences probably won't matter to you. `Picasso`, `Glide`, `UniversalImageLoader`, etc... All they do is making easier to load & cache images by performing all loading & caching stuff in background threads. You can choose any one of them and use in your projects.

Comment: k,but i want to know the what is internal implementation of image loading and what is caching mechanism? how these all libraries are calculating performance?