# Duplicates the Image in ListView when downloading

Tags: java, android

When the image has been downloaded, some of the images duplicates  in the listview rows, even though some of the row has no ImageID, The adapter view duplicates the downloaded images, when i suddenly scroll the listview

My code in getView

```
public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    int anotherPosition = position;


    if (inflater == null) {
        inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    }
    final Holder holder;
    if (convertView == null) {
        convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_item, null);
        holder = new Holder();

        holder.title = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.description);
        holder.exp = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.expiration);
        holder.someImages = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.listview_image);
        holder.isFavouriteImage = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.isFavourite);

        convertView.setTag(holder);
        convertView.setTag(R.id.listview_image, holder.someImages);
        convertView.setTag(R.id.description, holder.title);
        convertView.setTag(R.id.expiration, holder.exp);
        convertView.setTag(R.id.isFavourite, holder.isFavouriteImage);
    } else {
        holder = (Holder) convertView.getTag();
    }
    RowItemLoyalty rowItemLoyalty = data.get(position);

    if(rowItemLoyalty != null) {
        holder.someImages.setTag(position);
        holder.someImages.setImageBitmap(null);
        holder.title.setText(data.get(position).getDescription());
        holder.exp.setText(data.get(position).getDateEnd());

        Log.d("TrueOrFalse", String.valueOf(holder.someImages));
        if(holder.someImages != null ) {
            if (data.get(position).getImageId() != 0) {
                data.get(position).setBitmap(email, password, data.get(position).getImageId(), data.get(position).getBitmap(), new RowItemLoyalty.RetrieveBitmapListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onSuccess(Bitmap bitmap) {
                        Log.d("ImageID123", String.valueOf(data.get(position).getImageId()));
                        holder.someImages.setImageBitmap(null);
                        if (data.get(position).getBitmap() != null) {
                            Log.d("True", "True");
                            holder.someImages.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
                        }
                    }
                });
            }
        } else if(holder.someImages == null ) {
            Drawable placeholder = ContextCompat.getDrawable(context, R.drawable.placeholderwhite);
            holder.someImages.setImageDrawable(placeholder);
            Log.d("PlaceHolder2", String.valueOf(placeholder));
        }

        //----------- placeholder for imageview list -----------

        //holder.someImages.setImageBitmap(null);
        if (data.get(position).getBitmap() != null && holder.someImages != null) {
            holder.someImages.setImageBitmap(data.get(position).getBitmap());
            Log.d("PlaceHolder", "Implemented");
            Log.d("PlaceHolder", String.valueOf(data.get(position)));
        } else if (data.get(position).getBitmap() == null) {
            Drawable placeholder = ContextCompat.getDrawable(context, R.drawable.placeholderwhite);
            holder.someImages.setImageDrawable(placeholder);
            Log.d("PlaceHolder2", String.valueOf(placeholder));
        }

        //------------ for favourite logo-------------
        if (data.get(position).getIsFavorite() == false) {
            Drawable placeholderIsNotFavourite = ContextCompat.getDrawable(context, R.drawable.ic_favourite_icon);
            holder.isFavouriteImage.setImageDrawable(placeholderIsNotFavourite);
        } else if (data.get(position).getIsFavorite() == true) {
            Drawable favourited = ContextCompat.getDrawable(context, R.drawable.favourite_two);
            holder.isFavouriteImage.setImageDrawable(favourited);
        }
    }

    return convertView;
}
```

My Holder class

```
public static class Holder {
    TextView title;
    TextView exp;
    TextView tokensFor;
    ImageView promotionImages;
    ImageView isFavouriteImage;
}
```

Comment: Show code of `Holder` class

Comment: Maybe you should implement onFailure method on RowItemLoyalty.RetrieveBitmapListener

Comment: @maveň see the edited one

Comment: @eryllsalamanes  use loader library ... or chceck(in the library code) how they are checking if view was reused ... the error is obvious: you are starting to load image1 to viewholder1 then viewholder1 is reused so you starting to load image2 to viewholder1 ... fx image1 is big ... so first loading of image2 is finished ... then image1 is finished and images are f** up ... **in onSuccess you need to check if Bitmap that you get is still valid for this viewholder**

Comment: for example put imageid to holder and then compare it with `data.get(position).getImageId()` ... if they are different do not set it to ImageView ... asked bazillion times

Answer (score 1):

There are some useful libraries you can use to loading images like [Glide](https://github.com/bumptech/glide)

Also you can see this [Picasso v/s Imageloader v/s Fresco vs Glide](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29363321/picasso-v-s-imageloader-v-s-fresco-vs-glide)

Comment: im not sure if that libraries is applicable because we use an ID to fetch images

Answer (score 0):

Try using Universal Image Loader [Universal Image Loader](https://github.com/nostra13/Android-Universal-Image-Loader)

to set image on ImageView

Answer (score -1):

Remove checking `convertView == null` condition, like this:

```
convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_item, null);
holder = new Holder();

holder.title = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.description);
holder.exp = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.expiration);
holder.someImages = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.listview_image);
holder.isFavouriteImage = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.isFavourite);
```

Comment: That's how bad apps are made.... With this, so called, solution you get rid of view's recycling...

Comment: @Selvin Do you have a proper solution for that ? If YES, Please share it.