# How to cache the images into a folder on android device and load them when no network

Tags: android

I am having two fragments which fetches the images from server using volley library and display the image and image name in the recyclerview. My requirement is to cache the images into a folder while fetching the images from url and load the same images into the recyclerview when there is no internet availabe.any help will be appreciated...

Answer (score 0):

Use [Glide](https://www.google.co.in/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwikpoehwJbQAhXJKo8KHT8HD4UQFggaMAA&url=https%3A%2F%2Fgithub.com%2Fbumptech%2Fglide&usg=AFQjCNHZ_1a6kVBhhXyyVxpVvJaRrbqnZQ&sig2=5ZAjZMB4CumkVLQOJ9Xxfg&bvm=bv.137904068,d.c2I)  library for better image processing.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Glide, Fresco ,Picasso for image caching . If you are more interested in knowing their differences . there is a [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29363321/picasso-v-s-imageloader-v-s-fresco-vs-glide) .

Answer (score 0):

Use [Glide](https://github.com/bumptech/glide): it caches the image in memory once loaded, u can use it until app data is cleared. One of the best libraries.

add this to build gradle

dependencies {

compile 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:3.7.0'

compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:19.1.0'

}

then use glide to load image

Example :

Glide.with(this).load(R.drawable.sample).into(imageView);

Comment: am using the recyclerview . how to load the cached images into recyclerview when there is no internet availabe...

Comment: Glide automatically caches the image once its loaded .. it will show up even if there is no network. If i helped u to solve the issue , please select my replay as answer. if u have any doubts feel free to ask :)