# Android gradle Out Of Memory error

Tags: android, gradle, android-gradle-plugin, out-of-memory

```
Information:Gradle tasks [:app:generateDebugSources, :app:generateDebugAndroidTestSources, :app:mockableAndroidJar, :app:prepareDebugUnitTestDependencies, :core:generateDebugSources, :core:generateDebugAndroidTestSources, :core:mockableAndroidJar, :core:prepareDebugUnitTestDependencies]
```

> Error:Execution failed for task ':core:packageReleaseResources'.
>   java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space

I've tried to clean and rebuild the project, but it doesn't work.

Comment: check if you have any image included in your project of very large size

Comment: Please check this [OutofMemoryError](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41184166/java-lang-outofmemoryerror-failed-to-allocate-a-allocation-until-oom/44332261#44332261) to figure our your issue

Comment: Due to size of images very large