# GridView scroll not smooth

Tags: android, android-gridview

I am using Gridview in my App to show Images from a folder on Sdcard...
My issue is the Scrolling in the GridView, it is not as smooth as the Gallery App.
Here's the Adapter code -

```
public class GridViewAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

    // Declare variables
    private Activity activity;
    private String[] filepath;
    private String[] filename;

    private static LayoutInflater inflater = null;

    public GridViewAdapter(Activity a, String[] fpath, String[] fname) {
        activity = a;
        filepath = fpath;
        filename = fname;
        inflater = (LayoutInflater) activity
                .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

    }

    public int getCount() {
        return filepath.length;

    }

    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        View vi = convertView;
        if (convertView == null)

            vi = inflater.inflate(R.layout.gridview_item, null);

        // Locate the ImageView in gridview_item.xml
        ImageView img = (ImageView) vi.findViewById(R.id.image);


        // Set file name to the TextView followed by the position
        TextView txt = (TextView) vi.findViewById(R.id.name);

        // Decode the filepath with BitmapFactory followed by the position
        Bitmap bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(filepath[position]);

        // Set the decoded bitmap into ImageView
        img.setImageBitmap(bmp);
       txt.setText(filename[position]);
        return vi;
    }
}
```

How to solve this Issue and make the scrolling smooth?

Comment: You should use a ViewHolder

Answer (score 1):

You need to execute `BitmapFactory.decodeFile` in a separate thread, like this tutorial:
https://developer.android.com/training/displaying-bitmaps/process-bitmap.html

I suggest you use a cache, to not reload the images every time the user scroll:
https://developer.android.com/training/displaying-bitmaps/cache-bitmap.html

Answer (score 1):

You can do this.

1. Implemented Asynchronous image loading so that every image get loaded asynchronously
2. Make use of third party ImageLoaders and load images in Thumbnails size. For.ex [UniversalImageLoader](https://github.com/nostra13/Android-Universal-Image-Loader). check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29363321/picasso-v-s-imageloader-v-s-fresco-vs-glide)  more details
3. You can make use of `RecyclerView` with `GridLayoutManager` instead of `GridView`, it is more optimized control. for ex:http://www.android-examples.com/android-recyclerview-with-gridview-gridlayoutmanager/

additional reference:http://www.technotalkative.com/android-select-multiple-photos-from-gallery/

Answer (score 1):

BitmapFactory.decodeFile is heavy operation to perform on ui thread again and again. you have use some cache library.

You can use some image loading library like [Universal image loader](https://github.com/nostra13/Android-Universal-Image-Loader) , [Glide](https://github.com/bumptech/glide) or [picasso](http://square.github.io/picasso/) .

Please try this  using a holder.

```
class Holder{
ImageView img ;
TextView txt;
}


public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {      
    Holder holder;
    if (convertView == null)
 {
     convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.gridview_item, null);
       holder=new Holder();

    holder.img = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.image);

   holder.txt = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.name);

     convertView.setTag(holder)
    }
  else
{
  holder=(Holder)convertView.getTag();
 }


   Picasso.with(activity) .load(filepath[position]) .into(holder.img);
   txt.setText(filename[position]);
    return convertView;
}
```

Comment: I used Picasso but it doesn't show images..my Imageviews are blank..    Picasso.with(activity)
  .load(filepath[position])

  .into(img);

Comment: try to implement this using in a way as i edit my answer.

Comment: it's your choice to use glide or picasso. but for better result picasso is good.

Comment: Picasso couldn't load the Images... It was completely blank... So how can it be good as compared to Glide? :)

Comment: i can't say what would be issue that picasso is not showing images where glide is showing. but as compare in all manner picasso is good. Anyways i think your problem is solved using glide,so you can use glide.