# Picasso and Glide which one the best for get Image form server

Tags: android, gridview

Picasso and Glide which one the best for get Image form server and also give the example of custom grid view

Comment: you can easily find out it on google. This link mayh also helps you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29363321/picasso-v-s-imageloader-v-s-fresco-vs-glide

Comment: https://medium.com/@multidots/glide-vs-picasso-930eed42b81d

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are pros and cons of both the libraries but given below are couple of points:

1. **Memory consumption:** Glide occupies less memory as compared to Picasso. Reason being is Picasso loads full images doesn't matter what ImageView dimensions are mentioned, where as Glide loads image from server for the ImageView size (height/width)
2. **Library size:** Glide is heavier in terms of library size as compared to Picasso.
3. **Number of methods:** Glide is having more number of methods as compared to Picasso.
4. **GIF Support:** Picasso doesn't support GIF image loading.

P.S. There is a good article comes first in google search result https://inthecheesefactory.com/blog/get-to-know-glide-recommended-by-google/en