# Android best way to populate ViewPager with Images from Firebase Database

Tags: android, firebase, android-viewpager, firebase-realtime-database

Just a quick question as I'm facing an issue here:

What's the **best way**, in terms of **performances and speed**, to populate a ViewPager from a list of **URL stored on Firebase**,using Glide ??

I mean, should I pass an array containing the URLs to the ViewPager Constructor?
Get those URL from Firebase directly on the FragmentPagerAdapter class?

Cheers

Comment: Yes. Glide is even recommended by Google. Based on your needs you can switch between Glide and Fresco. Two of the best image loading libraries in my opinion

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/q/29363321/4625829

Comment: in my Android-FirebaseApp I rely on Picasso, http://square.github.io/picasso/

Comment: @Alexander I've also used Picasso. But then I discovered Glide. It has better performance because of it's image compression algorithm. You should give it a try

Comment: @RosárioPereiraFernandes may I ask how are allowing your users to upload their graphic data? In my application I convert their data to the desired bitmap quality and then upload it. Picasso has been cordial to the users all the way so far.

Comment: Same thing I do

Comment: Thanks guys for the comments. However, my issue is not whether or not using Glide (which I Love and use very often) but it's about when/where loading the Images URLs. What is the best and most efficient/quick way in terms of "architecture"

Answer (score 0):

Ok so after multiple tries and testing, here is what I have found to be the quickest:

**Load all the URLs into a String Array and pass it to the ViewPager Constructor**.

If you load the URLs on the fly directly from the ViewPager Class, it is slower.

I hope this will help others in the Future

Comment: Can I get the URLs from knowing just the appsot URL? Because, if I add some images on Firebase, I need not change the Studio code all over again.