# Android add shortcut icon from a url instead from drawable resources

Tags: android

I have an app where i am adding shortcut. I want to add shortcut icon image from URL path(images are stored on server and can be change) instead of using Drawable but i don't know how to do that. I tried to find a lot on this community. Any help?

Comment: what is shortcut there ? any view in the app or widget or something else. Elaborate

Comment: did you mean app icon?

Comment: yes...app icon..

Comment: @Abhishekshrivastava  this question should solve your problem http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1103027/how-to-change-an-application-icon-programmatically-in-android

Comment: @an_droid_dev this question does not provide the answer.
I want to add shortcuts and the shortcut icons should be from server url....
example - addShortcut(String appname,String appiconurl){

}

Comment: @Abhishekshrivastava The question is seriously unclear. According to what you wrote lower down in a comment to my answer you want to pass it as an extra. You need to explain better exactly what you are attempting.

Comment: @theblitz i have an app where there are some tiles in grid view and that icons are coming from server. now each item has add to shortcut option where i can put that specific item on homescreen to open their contents directly. and i have done that. But now i want to give them their respective icons image. But Intent.EXTRA_SHORTCUT_ICON only accepts resource id which are in drawable or accepts bitmap.
So i want to load url directly from server instead of taking from drawable

Comment: In that case use what Awais wrote below but put it into a variable instead of into an imageView

Comment: @Abhishekshrivastava were you able to get the answer to this?

Answer (score 0):

If the term used "shortcut icon" is a view or its descendants such as `ImageView`, then you can set the image, your application receive from the server by doing this :

add dependency to your `app.gradle` file :

```
compile 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:3.7.0'
```

and in the activity you can use this method to set the image to the `imageview` your app receive from the server :

```
ImageView imageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.image_view);
Glide.with(imageview.getContext()).load("https://url").error(R.drawable.not_found).centerCrop().into(imageview);
```

Comment: I personally prefer Picasso. If you want details about the differences then see this thread: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29363321/picasso-v-s-imageloader-v-s-fresco-vs-glide. Well worth the read

Comment: No...actually i want to add shortcut icons from this line of code
intent..putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SHORTCUT_ICON, R.drawable.your_image);
in place of drawable i want to load the image from my server

Comment: @theblitz thank you very much for your contribution but I used to use `picasso` then I moved to glide for this reason https://medium.com/@multidots/glide-vs-picasso-930eed42b81d

Comment: i think this cant be done with any image loading library. @theblitz you understand the question correctly?

Comment: @Abhishekshrivastava That's exactly what Picasso and Glide do. They fetch images from a URL and put them where you want in your app - including as icons.

Answer (score 0):

What you could do is first download that icon and store locally and then take that file path and use

```
ShortcutInfoCompat shortcutInfo = new ShortcutInfoCompat.Builder(this, UUID.randomUUID().toString())
                        .setIntent(intent) // !!! intent's action must be set on oreo
                        .setShortLabel(lable)
                        .setIcon(IconCompat.createWithAdaptiveBitmapContentUri(filePath)).build();
                ShortcutManagerCompat.requestPinShortcut(this, shortcutInfo, null);
```

Answer (score -2):

add this in your build.gradle

```
compile 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.5.2'
```

now you can load the image using following code

```
Picaso.with(this).load(urlHere).into(imageView);
```

Comment: Please see my question. I know how to load images from picasso,glide,volley etc. I want to add shortcut icon from url through intent services