# get Image from Json data and show it as cover image in RecyclerView android

Tags: java, android, json, deserialization, picasso

I am trying to get json data from Rest Api , deserialize it and show it to RecyclerView.

I am using retrofit 1.9. In JSONArray(s) I can see data api in logcat.

I can deserialize the data outside array of json, like body, title etc.

But there are some images as Array inside json. I have created two static inner class for appimage and testImage.

AppImage has 3 or four images. Test Image have only one image source.

At first I want to get TeaserimageSample to set it as RecyclerView heading image.

I am trying to get the src value from it. But could not get it how to do it.

I would also like to know if my model class is correct based on the given JSON. I have explained in detail inside the code.

**Edited Controller Class**

```
    public class NewsController {
    private static final String TAG = NewsController.class.getSimpleName();
    private UserCallbackListener mListener;
    private NewsRestApiManager mApiManager;

    public NewsController(UserCallbackListener listener) {
        mListener = listener;
        mApiManager = new NewsRestApiManager();
    }

    public void startFetching(){

        mApiManager.getNewsApi().getNews(new Callback<String>() {

            @Override
            public void success(String s, Response response) {
                Log.d(TAG, "JSON :: " + s);

                try {
                    JSONArray array = new JSONArray(s);

                    for(int i = 0; i < array.length(); i++) {
                        JSONObject object = array.getJSONObject(i);

                        NewsModel news = new NewsModel();
                        news.setTitle( object.optString( "title") );
                        news.setBody( object.optString( "body" ) );

                        ArrayList<NewsModel.AppImage> list = new ArrayList();
                        JSONArray imageArray =object.getJSONArray("appImages");
                        for(int j=0; j<imageArray.length();j++){
                            NewsModel.AppImage appImages  = new NewsModel.AppImage();
                            appImages.setSrc(imageArray.getJSONObject( j ).getString( "src" ));
                            list.add(appImages);
                        }
                        news.setAppImages( list );

                        JSONObject jo=object.getJSONObject( "teaserImageSmall​" );
                        NewsModel.TeaserImageSmall coverImage=new NewsModel.TeaserImageSmall();
                        coverImage.setSrc( jo.optString( "src" ));
                        news.setTeaserImageSmall(coverImage);
                        mListener.onFetchProgress(news);

                    }

                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    mListener.onFetchFailed();
                }


                mListener.onFetchComplete();
            }

            @Override
            public void failure(RetrofitError error) {
                Log.d(TAG, "Error :: " + error.getMessage());
                mListener.onFetchComplete();
            }
        });

    }
    public interface UserCallbackListener{
        void onFetchStart();
        void onFetchProgress(NewsModel news);
        void onFetchProgress(List<NewsModel> userList);
        void onFetchComplete();
        void onFetchFailed();
    }
}
```

**My Edited Adapter Class Where I set Picasso to set image for cover image. But still I can see nothing in recyclerview**

```
...............
    // create new views (invoked by the layout manager)
    @Override
    public NewsHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext())
                .inflate(R.layout.news_row_layout,parent,false);
        return new NewsHolder(view);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(NewsHolder holder, int position) {

        final NewsModel currentNews = mNews.get(position);
        Picasso.with(holder.itemView.getContext());
        Picasso.with(holder.itemView.getContext()).load(currentNews.getTeaserImageSmall().getSrc()).into( holder.newsImage );

        holder.newsImage.setImageResource( R.drawable.image1 );
        holder.newsHeadline.setText(currentNews.getTitle());
        holder.newsDate.setText(currentNews.getPostDate());

    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return mNews.size();
    }


    public class NewsHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

        public CardView cardView;
        public ImageView newsImage;
        public TextView newsHeadline;
        public TextView newsDate;

        public NewsHolder(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            newsImage=(ImageView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.news_picture);
            newsHeadline=(TextView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.news_headline);
            newsDate=(TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.news_date);
            cardView=(CardView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.cardview_news);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: @Benjamin I have given in my question the api mager

Comment: can you post API link ? I mean from where you getting this json response?

Comment: I think you cannot have authorization to see it. https://app.blu-pa.com/api/news.. But the json data is same like this

Comment: Because I cann see all data in logcat. I can also see body , text, update date in recyclerview. But I stuck with issue with image at this moment

Comment: ok I am trying this one

Comment: i am not able to get exact image link from that response. I mean that links from src tags are not working.

Comment: why are you even using Gson here if you are returning the whole response as a String which you then deserialize by hand?

Comment: @Benjamin Sorry I am still very new in handling so complex stuff. I have seen one tutorial . and try to implement it in my code. I got response from api with this code. that is why I wrote in this way

Comment: It is shwoing error, Cannot resolve convert GsonConstructor.

Comment: see my updated response below

Comment: I have mentioned in my question that I am using retrofit 1.9. is there no wan to loop through the appIMage array  and TestImageSample and get the image?.

Answer (score 1):

`appImages.setSrc( imageArray.optString( Integer.parseInt( "src" )`

This is showing you error because you are receving "src" as `String` and you trying to use it as `int`

Comment: @V-rund, how can I modify it?

Comment: `appImages.setSrc(imageArray.optString( "src" ))` use this. Also i suspected that images aren't loading from url. i guess there might be different path for that

Comment: @V-rundPuro-hit iam still getting error with appImages.setSrc(imageArray.optString( "src" ))

Comment: getString(int) in JSONArray cannot be applied to java.lang.string. I have edited this line in code

Comment: @V-rundPuro-hit I am still not getting why src is not working. why this error i sshowing

Comment: @ktina src not working means? you are not able to see image ??

Comment: @ysl, Yes I can see the image, url is fine, api is fine, everything is alright. What I want to do,at fisrt call TeaserImageSmall class in json deserilization as described in code , get the src as in controller class and then in adpter class show in picasso at fisrt. THen next step , loop through the appimage array. I just stuck with this problem. First step I want to solve TestImageSmall problem. then we can go to next step

Answer (score 0):

You can directly show image from web without downloading it with

```
public static Drawable loadImage(String url) {
    try {
        InputStream inputStream = (InputStream) new URL(url).getContent();
        return Drawable.createFromStream(is, "src name");
    } catch (Exception e) {
        return null;
    }
}
```

and setting it to the ImageView.

Otherwise you can use some library like picasso, with

```
Picasso.with(context)
   .load(url)
   .placeholder(R.drawable.placeholder) //optional
   .resize(width, height)               //optional  
   .into(image);                        //your image view
```

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29363321/picasso-v-s-imageloader-v-s-fresco-vs-glide) a discussiuon on some Picasso alternatives (Imageloader, Fresco, Glide)

Comment: @Nicole its a rest api, no one can use without authorization, I have make as offline version also. So I want make a deserialization at fisrt and then show it to recyclerview.

Answer (score 0):

As you can see in response :

```
"appImages": [
  {
    "alt": "",
    "src": "http://www.blu-pa.com/sites/www.blu-pa.com/files/DSC_7549.JPG",
    "_id": "599b39a20dbf4e002b875f71"
  },
  {
    "alt": "",
    "src": "http://www.blu-pa.com/sites/www.blu-pa.com/files/DSC_7531.JPG",
    "_id": "599b39a20dbf4e002b875f70"
  },
  {
    "alt": "",
    "src": "http://www.blu-pa.com/sites/www.blu-pa.com/files/DSC_7349.JP",
    "_id": "599b39a20dbf4e002b875f6f"
  },
  {
    "alt": "",
    "src": "http://image4.JPG",
    "_id": "599b39a20dbf4e002b875f6e"
  },
  {
    "alt": "",
    "src": "http://image4.JPG",
    "_id": "599b39a20dbf4e002b875f6d"
  }
],
```

appImages is jsonArray, to get value of src from this you need to get jsonobject first the from that json object the string value for src like this:

```
JSONArray imageArray =object.getJSONArray("appImages");
for(int j=0; j<imageArray.length();j++){
     NewsModel.AppImage appImages  = new NewsModel.AppImage(); 
     appImages.setSrc(imageArray.getJsonObject(j).getString("src"));

}

list.add(appImages); //how to add image after iteration
```

try this

Comment: How can I get teaserImageSmall​ in this case. I have edited my Controller Class. Could you please have a look

Comment: Could you please tell me how can get image in picasso in this case. I want zo get only testImageSamll at first. Picasso.with(holder.itemView.getContext()).load( /* I want to set imagew source from TeaserImageSmall*/);

Comment: for picasso:- Picasso.with(holder.itemView.getContext()).load( from json object of teaserImageSmall get string for **src**);i.e **Picasso.with(holder.itemView.getContext()).load(object.getJSONObject("teaserImageSmall​").getString("src"))**

Comment: I just edited my question, the adapter class also. still I am not getting anything :( I also write the code for testImageSample. Could you plaese have a look

Comment: here you are not setting any image so set here and then add newsmodel to list i.e. ** JSONObject Jo= object.getJSONObject("teaserImageSmall​");
                        NewsModel.TeaserImageSmall coverImage=new NewsModel.TeaserImageSmall();
                      coverImage.setSrc(Jo.getString(‌​"src"));
                        mListener.onFetchProgress(news);**

Comment: NewsModel.TeaserImageSmall coverImage=new NewsModel.TeaserImageSmall();
                    coverImage.setSrc( jo.optString( "src" ));
                        mListener.onFetchProgress(news);
                    } you are just creating a object for teaserImage but not setting to newsModel anywhere so you will not find the same in adapter class until it is set somewhere

Comment: still recyclerview is empty

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/152523/discussion-between-nikhil-jadhav-and-ktina).

Answer (score 0):

There are two possibilities.

- The first one is your imageView's height attribute is zore.
- The second one is your url is not correct enough to load image.

So first try to set valid height to imageView, if you can not get any success, try to fix your url.

### Fix the Url

Add this method into your helper class and use it with Picasso or Glide;

```
public static String getUrl(String the_url){
    try {
        URI uri = null;
        URL url = new URL(the_url);
        uri = new URI(url.getProtocol(), url.getUserInfo(), url.getHost(), url.getPort(), url.getPath(), url.getQuery(), url.getRef());
        return uri.toASCIIString();
    } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (URISyntaxException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return "no_image_url";
}
```

Your code should be like;

```
Picasso.with(holder.itemView.getContext()).load(MyHelper.getUrl(currentNews.getTeaserImageSmall().getSrc())).into( holder.newsImage );
```

When you open an image via your browser, you can see the image but sometimes Android could't find that image. With this url conversation, Picasso or Glide can find the url.

And also I met with this issue when working with Picasso library. I could't fix it and then I migrated to Glide library and my problem has gone.

Comment: Sorry but, can I implement the json array  in NewsController class.. because your code is not relavant to my code

Comment: I'm sorry but I don't have any other idea to fix your problem. I faced with this problem , i did the above steps and fixed it.

Comment: ok. but I think this in not relavant my code. Because you see, I have controller class, and my url is there in json format. I am facing correct deserialization of the source. that is my question so far

Comment: ok, try to add this to your imageview layout and be sure that imageview's layout_height attribute is wrap_content.  `android:adjustViewBounds="true"  android:scaleType="fitXY"` and before compiling project, clean the project and then compile it.

Comment: yes I set this. but this does not change anything inside code.