# Recyclerview is Laggy?

Tags: java, android, android-recyclerview

I am following the tutorial in this [link](https://www.androidauthority.com/how-to-build-an-image-gallery-app-718976/) to learn about RecyclerView. The tutorial loads images from drawable folder. When I do the same the app just runs out of memory. So I made a little change to resize images.

```
@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(MyAdapter.ViewHolder viewHolder, int i) {
    viewHolder.title.setText(galleryList.get(i).getImage_title());
    viewHolder.img.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.CENTER_CROP);
    viewHolder.img.setImageResource((galleryList.get(i).getImage_ID()));
}
```

Changed the 3rd line to this

```
viewHolder.img.setImageDrawable(scaleImage(galleryList.get(i).getImage_ID(), ScaleFactor));
```

And defined scaleImage as

```
private Drawable scaleImage(int imageId, float scaleFactor)
{
    Drawable image = context.getResources().getDrawable(imageId);

    if ((image == null) || !(image instanceof BitmapDrawable)) {
        return image;
    }

    Bitmap b = ((BitmapDrawable)image).getBitmap();

    int sizeX = Math.round(image.getIntrinsicWidth() * scaleFactor);
    int sizeY = Math.round(image.getIntrinsicHeight() * scaleFactor);

    Bitmap bitmapResized = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(b, sizeX, sizeY, false);

    image = new BitmapDrawable(context.getResources(), bitmapResized);

    return image;
}
```

But as I scroll RecyclerView lags until It loads the coming rows which I think is because I load each image individually and then resize it. Is there a way to do this asychronously?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's become cause you are resizing the image, it's a heavy process.
try to resize images async or use image loader libs.

There are some useful libraries you can use for loading images like [Glide](https://github.com/bumptech/glide)

Also, you can see this [Picasso v/s Imageloader v/s Fresco vs Glide](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29363321/picasso-v-s-imageloader-v-s-fresco-vs-glide)

Comment: can glide be used for loading images on device?

Comment: yes, please read this [tutorials](https://futurestud.io/tutorials/glide-getting-started).

glide has many methods for loading images, you can load images from url, file and from drawables.