# What is the correct way in android to load images from URL in a ListView without delay

Tags: android, listview, delay, image-loading

I have to show a list of posts, some of them with images (think in something like twitter) and load more when I do scroll on the ListView but images take some seconds to appear. How can I do the load without delay? Currently I'm doing it with *Picasso*

Here my code:

```
 ListView lv = findViewById(R.id.list_feed);
    arrayPosts = fillArray(data);
    adapter= new PostAdapter(this, arrayPosts);
    lv.setOnScrollListener(new AbsListView.OnScrollListener() {

        @Override
        public void onScroll(AbsListView view, int firstVisibleItem, int visibleItemCount,
                             int totalItemCount) {

            int lastIndexInScreen = visibleItemCount + firstVisibleItem;

            if (lastIndexInScreen >= totalItemCount && totalItemCount > 0 && !isLoading) {
                isLoading = true;

                loadMore();
            }
        }
    });

    lv.setAdapter(adapter);
```

My Adapter's getView() method:

```
public View getView(int i, View view, ViewGroup viewGroup) {

    Post post = (Post) getItem(i);
    view = LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.row_post_item, null);
    (...)

    Picasso.with(context).load(post.getImgProfile()).into(imgProfile);
    Picasso.with(context).load(post.getImagePost()).into(imgPost);

    (...)
    return view;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't do it with no delay at all. The download speed depends on Internet connection & the device, so some delay has to exist, unless you pre-load images one page up front in advance (that's how most apps do it). But even then fast scrolling may cause some delay.

I would suggest **[Glide](https://github.com/bumptech/glide)**. 
It is much faster than Picasso. It handles the download to memory and cache utilization better than Picasso. It acts better with GIFs, and prevents nasty OutOfMemoryError. Of course you can load placeholders until your image loads etc.

**It even comes recommended by Google.**

Cheers

Comment: I'm testing Glide and the performance is so much better than Picasso's. As you said, some delay has to exists. How could I pre-load images as you said most apps do?

Comment: Long answer and many ways to do this. I'll try cutting the logic short and hope you understand with one simple example :)
In background try picking up all images and downloading them manually (from your own code logic) to cache or however you fancy serializing. And when the adapter needs to load an image check if it is already downloaded, if it is just load it from local source you used, if not use Glide. But only download in background with async method. Hope you get the picture :)

Comment: But the above is really not mandatory. I sometimes find it to be a waste of time and code. You can achieve a really cool effect by having a nice placeholder image, and optimizing the images you download remotely with Glide. And Glide really utilizes cache very well.

Answer (score 1):

`Picasso` is a very good way to load images  because of its caching abilities , still I would recommend you read this [answer](http://www.stackoverflow.com/a/33210679) and then decide which option you want to use according to your specific needs.