# does picasso optimize bitmaps and network requests?

Tags: android, picasso

I'm using picasso to handle image related stuff in my android app. I'm using version 2.5.2.

I'll have one specific layout where i will load tons of images from the internet. Really LOTS OF IMAGES.

So before start im concerned about how will picasso handle memory and network optimizations.

1-The images will be shown using a `recyclerview` so i hope it will help to reduce the memory required
2-In my specific scenario MANY IMAGES WILL BE REPEATED. So lets say i have 1k images (ex): the first 100 images will be loaded from the very same url, then 900 images from different urls.

The question is:
1- will picasso trigger 100 requests to load the very same image? or will it keep some local cache and ignore 99?
2- will it use some mechanism to save memory when loading the images? like using the same bitmap when showing the very same image

if anyone can advice me in a lib more apropriated to my requirements i'm very thankful

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Picasso v/s Imageloader v/s Fresco vs Glide](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29363321/picasso-v-s-imageloader-v-s-fresco-vs-glide)

Answer (score 3):

Please Find the InLine Answers

> 1- will picasso trigger 100 requests to load the very same image? or will it keep some local cache and ignore 99?

The Images are cached and not downloaded each time Picasso does have an inbuilt cache to handle this in fact all of the image loading libraries such as Glide, Fresco and Picasso have this built in

> 2- will it use some mechanism to save memory when loading the images? like using the same bitmap when showing the very same image

The inbuilt cache handles this for you, internally all these library track if the source has changed using the cache expirartion TAG before they download it again.

> if anyone can advice me in a lib more apropriated to my requirements i'm very thankful

Use any one of the image loading libraries such as Glide, Fresco and Picasso, **but google recommends Glide**

Comment: @Rafael Lima what did you end up using Glide or picasso