# Glide loads images slowly

Tags: android, imageview, android-glide

I have an issue with Glide. In the first fragment I have a stack of views with background loaded with Glide. In the second fragment there is recyclerview with this kind of views. But when I navigate to the second fragment the background flickers. I tried to remove animation and change disk cache strategy, but without success. I am loading background with this

```
Glide.with(context)
        .load(url)
        .diskCacheStrategy(DiskCacheStrategy.DATA)
        .dontAnimate()
        .listener(listener)
        .into(imageView)
```

When I tried to investigate, I found that the flicker occurs when the image is loaded from disk cache. For the second time, it loads from memory cache and everything is ok. I think the problem occur because of views' different size. But do not have clue to solve the issue.

Comment: Use Fresco instead of Glide. Check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29363321/picasso-v-s-imageloader-v-s-fresco-vs-glide) link to compare them